# Clion "forgets" definition of a symbol

Tags: c++, clion

In my `ActionUnit.cpp` class I use the member variable `mActionRootNodeList` in the [getToolBarList()](https://github.com/Mudlet/Mudlet/pull/866/files#diff-266015a179f93c26b081a16a8213937eR282) and [getEasyButtonBarList()](https://github.com/Mudlet/Mudlet/pull/866/files#diff-266015a179f93c26b081a16a8213937eR350) methods. CLion knows the definition of it in one method but not in the other. Why?

[image]

This is using 2017.1.

Comment: Does it compile?

Comment: Yep, compiles fine!

Comment: All I can think of is maybe an invisible control character has got into the name.   Have you tried deleting that unrecognised one, and copy/pasting the good one in it's place?  And/or, try the https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7448-zero-width-characters-locator

Comment: Not it unfortunately, ctrl+f of ``mActionRootNodeList`` highlights both instances, copy/pasting the good one over the bad one didn't fix it either.

Comment: That happens sometimes. It's an indexer problem, but it usually sorts itself after a short time. You can either wait or try one of the following ways to sort it out: 1. Modify CMakeLists 2. Reopen Clion

Comment: I tried ``Invalidate caches and restart`` and it worked. Could you post it as an answer so I can mark this solved?